# Move zoomed image on mousemove

Tags: jquery, zooming, mousemove

I'm creating my own zoom functionality. I swap out the image for a x2 size image which is supposed to be moveable on click. The movement is giving me trouble though. I've cobbled together some code from around the net. It works but not only moves left and down. I'd like it to move with the mouse and the image is centered on the mouse and also constrain to the dimensions of the element enclosing it. Anyone have any thoughts? Link: http://bigideaadv.com/pic_site/?p=95

```
    jQuery("div.zoom2 img.rsImg2").mousemove(function(e) {
        var zoom = jQuery(this);
        var position = zoom.position();

        //console.log(position);

        jQuery(".rsImg2").css({"left" : position.left, "top" : position.top});

        // the first parameter (e) is automatically assigned an event object

        var parentOffset = jQuery(this).parent().offset();
        //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

        jQuery(".rsImg2").css({"left" : relX, "top" : relY});
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to debug this on your site, it would help if you can create a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) of this.

However, I think the problem is that you're changing the position of the `img` that is firing the `mousemove` event. This moves the `img` element away from the mouse cursor and so the event will no longer fire unless you move back into the `img` (to the right or down).

Instead, try firing the event on the parent

```
jQuery("div.zoom2").mousemove(function(e) {
```

You'll have to modify some of the jQuery to point to the right elements. Also, are you sure you don't want to set the negative of the cursor movement? Like so:

```
jQuery(".rsImg2").css({"left" : -relX, "top" : -relY});
```

Or something akin to this. Play around with it. If you create a jsFiddle, we can help out a bit better =)

Good luck!

Comment: Great. This little bit helped me out a bunch. I used the main div.zoom2 container for the mousemove and doubled the parent offset to get the image to bind to the middle of the cursor.  

var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left*2;
var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top*2;
Thanks again for the help.